# System forgets settings and doesn't allow to install applications after reboot

Tags: settings

I have bought BLAUPUNKT ENDEAVOUR-1000 HD month ago, installed couple of games and apps, then moved them to the sd card, it was working perfect, then I turned it off and now wach time you re start, the tablet require new set up (as its brand new) and shows 0.00 KB internal memory, sd card is free, so I can't install anything and my tablet does not remember my settings, accounts etc. Should I try with the place where I have it and the warranty, or am I missing something? Tried with Root explorer, now when I connect it to the pc and try to access on the tablet, system, then the tablet restart by itself.

Answer (score 0):

it's the same problem with my 1000HD in three times and, sorry, there isn't a solve. You must get the warranty and put it on ebay if it's ok after the repair.
It's not a hardware problem it seems to be a firmware problem and it will going on and on. You will get it as good as new from warranty repair an some weeks later - kawoom, same problem. There is no fun with this device. Sorry.

Best regards and so sorry for my english

Marko